# Basis of topology $[x, +\infty)$

Tags: general-topology

Why the topology over $\Bbb R$ generated by basis $[x, +\infty)$ is $[x, +\infty)\cup (x, +\infty)$ are the open set on this topology thank you.

Comment: The topology is $\{[x,+\infty)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}\cup \{(x,+\infty)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}\cup\{\mathbb R,\emptyset\}.$ Without the braces, as you've written it, is just $[x,+\infty).$

Comment: Hint: $$(x,+\infty)=\bigcup_{y>x} [y,+\infty)$$

Comment: Why basis  B generated this union

Comment: What is $B?$ The union of open sets is an open set.

Comment: B=[x, +∞) is Basis

Comment: $[x,+\infty)$ is not a basis, it is a single subset of $\mathbb R.$ $B=\{[x,+\infty)\mid x\in \mathbb R\}$ is a basis.

Comment: The union of semi open set give an open set

Comment: What is a semi-open set?

Comment: If $B$ is a basis for a topology $T,$ then every element of $B$ is an element of $T.$ That is, $B\subseteq T.$

Answer (score 0):

To show that a basis $\mathcal{B}$ generates a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$, it is enough to show that (1) each $B \in \mathcal{B}$ is open in $X$ (i.e., $B \in \mathcal{T}$) and (2) for each open set $U$ of $X$ and for each $x \in U$, there exists $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq U$.

Here, the proposed basis is $\mathcal{B} = \{ [x, \infty) | x \in \mathbb{R} \}$, and the proposed topology is $\mathcal{T} = \{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ [x, \infty) | x \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ (x, \infty) | x \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

The first condition is straightforward.

For the second condition, let's consider a few cases.

Case 1: $U = \emptyset$. There is no $x$ satisfying $x \in U$, so there's nothing to check.

Case 2: $U = \mathbb{R}$. Taking any $x \in U = \mathbb{R}$, the set $[x, \infty) \in \mathcal{B}$ obviously contains $x$ and is a subset of $\mathbb{R} = U$.

Case 3: $U = [u, \infty)$. Let $x \in U$; this implies $x \ge u$. Note that the set $[x, \infty) \in \mathcal{B}$ contains $x$ and is contained in $U$, since any element $y \in [x, \infty)$ satisfies $y \ge x$, which means $y \ge u$ and so $y \in U$.

Case 4: $U = (u, \infty)$. Let $x \in U$; this implies $x > u$. Again, the set $[x, \infty) \in \mathcal{B}$ contains $x$ and is contained in $U$, since any element $y \in [x, \infty)$ satisfies $y \ge x$, which means $y > u$ and so $y \in U$.

And we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: If this answer was helpful, consider upvoting and accepting it.